# Angular 2 how to extend class which has dependency injections

Tags: angular, oop, dependencies, extends

i have the following class which i want to extend.

```
export class AngularComponent {
    constructor(
        private r: Renderer2,
        private editorService: AngularEditorService,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: any,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        @Attribute("tabindex") defaultTabIndex: string,
        @Attribute("autofocus") private autoFocus: any
    )  
}
```

So i create the following class:

```
export class EnhancedComponent extends AngularComponent{
    constructor(private r: Renderer2, private editorService: AngularEditorService){
        super(r,editorService, ...)
    }
}
```

However i don't know how to pass the other dependencies

```
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: any,
@Attribute("tabindex") defaultTabIndex: string,
@Attribute("autofocus") private autoFocus: any
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do the trick:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-simplify-components-with-typescript-inheritance/

Basically you use the `Injector` class to retrieve your injections instead of constructor injection.

Comment: Thx, but how can i do it in my case. In my case i can't modify the base class. It comes from a library ...

Comment: If you can't modify the base class, you probably need to wrap it into your own BaseComponent which instantiates the lib component.